# Sitecore 7 Search in all content

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore7

I am programming a search site for a Sitecore Based Website. I have been able to come to this point.

```
 var query = SearchContext.GetQueryable<MySearchResultItem>().Where(i =>        
                       i.ItemContent.Contains(this._View.SearchTerm)).ToArray();
```

MySearchResultsItem is defined as follows.

```
public class MySearchResultItem
{
    // Will match the _name field in the index
    [IndexField("_name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [IndexField(Sitecore.ContentSearch.BuiltinFields.Content)]
    public string ItemContent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

When I do a search with

```
[IndexField("_name")]
```

, I am getting the right results. But I would like to search in all fields of the items, and I think it is possible with
    `[IndexField(Sitecore.ContentSearch.BuiltinFields.Content)]`.

What am I doing wrong? Which IndexField should I use to query all the content?

Thanx

Comment: Your code is correct. Are you sure the value you're searching for (this._View.SearchTerm) has been indexed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Sitecore.ContentSearch.BuiltinFields.Content` field in the index only contains content from binary files in the media library. If you look at the config it references `Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor`.

To search across all fields you would need to add a custom `IComputedIndexField` to the `<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">` which aggregated all the fields you want to search on, or just include all the fields you want to search on in your linq query.

Comment: This is incorrect. The _content field aggregates all fields from the item to allow full text searching. Media item content is just part of what is indexed in this field.

http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/07/Sitecore-7-Making-Google-Part-3.aspx